# SharedPreferences é indicado para guardar o estado da aplicação?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

já procurei em vários sites gringos porém não encontrei nada, inclusive aqui.

Tenho um problema no aplicativo que sempre que o usuario minimiza ele e usa o celular para outra coisa em celulares com pouca memoria ela é apagada para novos dados, então quando o aplicativo é aberto novamente (que estava em background) ele sempre da erro e fecha por que um objeto não esta salvo, estava na memória e depois de apagar ele fica null fazendo acontecer o erro.

Minha pergunta é aconselhável fazer isso com SharedPreferences? Pois sempre vejo ele sendo utilizado com strings, int, bollean etc. ou existe outro método mais eficiente?

Comment: Para esse efeito o normal é utilizar o Bundle passado ao método `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: Isso pode ser de grande ajuda, vou pesquisar aqui como utilizar, brigadão!

Comment: Uma duvida: Para salvar ele entra no [ onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)] e para recarregar?

Comment: No `onCreate()`, como explicado lá.

Comment: Sim, mas no app a MainActivity não passa novamente pelo onCreate, então coloquei no onRestart

Comment: Se a Activity não é recreada(onCreate() chamado) então o problema é outro. Sugiro que faça nova pergunta, com código e log de erros, e explique exactamente o que está a acontecer.